# What are ways to force users to commit certain files allways together in SVN?

Tags: svn, pre-commit-hook

I have 3 files .xml .cs and . h that I want always to be modified and committed together. They are all in different directories. Users are likely to forget modify/commit all accordingly.

How can I force them to commit all three files together ?

I want them to see an error message explaining why the commit was rejected.

I can perhaps try some pre-commit hook. If someone could provide a general hook-script example, that would be very helpful.

Or are there other effective ways ?

We use Linux CentOS server + Win/Tortoise workstations.

Comment: I saw this post already, but it is other use-case...

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/926354/grouping-committed-files-together-as-a-single-commit-after-youve-already-comm

Comment: https://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-changelists.html